# Browser automatically encoding URL

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, url-encoding

I am having a strange issue with the URL encoding and browser. I have this following URL:

```
http://abcd.com/?isPosm=1&callBackUrl=http%3A%2F%2FmyAnotherDomian%2FPOSM%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fadf.task-flow%3Fadf.tfDoc%3D%252FWEB-INF%252Ftask-flows%252Fcatalog-edit-task-flow.xml%26adf.tfId%3Dcatalog%26_adf.ctrl-state%3Dtry2tadtl_32%26articleReference%3D10C00135%26previousView%3Dcatalog-home%26fromUCM%3Dtrue%26articleType%3Dposm%26developer%3Dcentral
```

In my machine when I am paste and go this URL it is changing to:

```
http://abcd.com/index.htm?isPosm=1&callBackUrl=http%253A%252F%252FmyAnotherDomain%252FPOSM%252Fapp%252Fpages%252Fadf.task-flow%253Fadf.tfDoc%253D%25252FWEB-INF%25252Ftask-flows%25252Fcatalog-edit-task-flow.xml%2526adf.tfId%253Dcatalog%2526_adf.ctrl-state%253D14a6xfftpt_9%2526articleReference%253D10C00135%2526previousView%253Dcatalog-home%2526fromUCM%253Dtrue%2526articleType%253Dposm%2526developer%253Dcentral
```

Clearly `http%3A%2F%2Fuat-pppstore.moet-hennessy.biz` is getting encoded to `http%253A%252F%252Fuat-pppstore.moet-hennessy.biz`. Why this is happening? I found this in both Firefox and Chrome. What is strange is that it is not behaving same in another Firefox running on other machine.

Any pointer would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example your first request was to the root directory, it got changed to "index.htm".  The browser would never put this url on (it has no idea if it exists), this suggests that the error is in your server, redirecting the user to the "index.htm" page and re-encoding an encoded url.